# Are tours (e.g. Foundation's Joyride and Bootstrap's Tour) helpful?

Tags: help

I have a site with a lot of different functionality and I'm having a hard time with guiding users as to what to do and when, especially because they don't have to do tasks in any specific order.

Having overlays like those in [Foundation Joyride](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html) or [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) saying "you can do *this* here" and/or "click here to do *this*" I feel could be helpful, but I haven't seen it in the real world yet (can't find any sites with it) or know if it's actually helpful or just gets in the way/gimmicky.

Is there another term for these types of help dialogs? Do you know of any sites that use it and does it actually help or is it just gimmicky?

Comment: Related: [How long should a good onboarding experience be?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64967/how-long-should-a-good-onboarding-experience-be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Tour](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Tour)" and "Walkthrough" are the common terms for this type of functionality. Zurb's Joyride is one approach to this using modal dialogs. There's a twitter bootstrap alternative called "[Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/)".

I believe it's a fairly common approach for notifying users of new features to the system. It's helpful to have the system point out what's new for you within the interface when you have a system that already have a lot of stuff in it.

Here are some examples:

Facebook

[image]

Google

[image]

WordPress

[image]

This is much less helpful for walking a new user through for onboarding, since users probably just want to start doing stuff as oppose to reading through all of these little blurbs. See article: [Are UI walkthroughs evil](http://tapity.com/are-ui-walkthroughs-evil/). You should always strive to design the UI so new users can get started without a walkthrough. Only if you're dealing with an immersive experience or functionality that's crucial to your system but not readily discoverable should you consider onboarding UI. Even then, there are [other approaches](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/11/mobile-onboarding-beginners-guide/) to this than modals.

Comment: Early versions of the Mac Operating System had a similar functionality called 'Balloon Help' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balloon_help.  You could usefully turn it on or off.

Comment: It seems like Wordpress calls those "Admin Pointers". So I'm not sure if we've came to a standardized term for these yet.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is "Onboarding" one of the most recent examples I've seen was when I began using [Slack](https://slack.com/). They have animation hotspots appear on the page for you to discover what each interface element does.

For a higher level exploration of the topic you could look at http://www.useronboard.com/.

And of course a [quick search of this site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=onboarding) will show a number of interesting questions.